# Object-Oriented Design For Data Frame Transformation

Tags: python, pandas, oop

I'm trying to apply object oriented design to my data science project. For data cleaning, we usually start off with a table(dataframe) and then do transformations on this dataframe(For example, creating a new column based on existing column, add two columns together etc).

My initial thought on this (in python) was basically create a class Data that would have an underlying pandas dataframe as a private member and provide extra methods in the class to transform the data. After i reached this step, i was wondering:

1. Am i doing object-oriented programming for the sake of doing it? Does this bring any advantage in comparison to just writing the code in pure pandas and forget about creating my own class?

```
class Data:

    def __init__(self, df):

        self._df = df

    def clean_dataframe(self):
        """
            Does some operation on self._df, eg adds a new column
            and sets self._df to the updated dataframe
        """
        self._df = some_operations(self._df)
```

Or just do:

```
def clean_dataframe(df):
    df = some_operations(df)
    return df

df = clean_dataframe(df)
```

2. On a completely different note. Once we do a transformation from dataframe(d0) to dataframe(d1), in a object oriented sense, do i need to create a new class for d1 since the underlying dataframe has changed(for example, added a new column). In the same example , note that we redefined self._df after the clean_dataframe method.
   Should I be changing this variable or should be creating a new variable or even a new class to represent the transformed data.

Very new to Object-Oriented design and would love to gain more perspective.

Comment: Please show an example of what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Compiling several helper functions for data processing, definitely makes sense, especially if there is need for repetitive use. I am not quite sure whether creating a Data class offers any exquisite advantages, unless there are other objects one would like to "bundle" ala C-type struct.

That said, for modelling purposes one might often resort to writing custom made estimators, when off-the-shelf doesn't seem adequate.

With respect to 2, in my opinion you don't need to create a separate dataframe, especially if the only difference is an extra column. As a cautionary tangent, one issue I have occasionally faced however is dataframes becoming too clunky, which might even affect IDE performance. But this also depends on the datatypes and size of the original dataframe.